# Make whole <li> as link with proper HTML

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I know this has been up a lot of times before, but I couldn't find any solution in my specific case.

I've got a navigation bar and I want the whole `<li>`'s to be "linked" or "clickable" if you will. Now only the `<a>` (and the `<div>`'s I've fiddled with) is "clickable".

I've tried the `li a {display: inner-block; height: 100%; width: 100%}` method but the results where just horrible.

The source can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/prplxr/BrcZK/

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="innermenu">    
                    <ul id="menulist">       
                        <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.php"><div class="menulink">Lnk1</div></a></li>
                        <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.php"><div class="menulink">Lnk2</div></a></li>
                        <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.php"><div class="menulink">Lnk3</div></a></li>
                        <li class="menuitem"><a href="index.php"><div class="menulink">Lnk4</div></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do anyone have a neat solution to this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want `<li>` has clickable then you need to use Javascript, is that fine?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

- Get rid of the `<div>`s.
- Set the `<a>` tags to have `display: block`
- Move the padding from the `<li>` to the `<a>`.
- The `<li>`s will need to be either floated or `display: inline-block`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8yQ57/

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve! Thank you very much, Steve!

Comment: Saved me hours trying to get a link to apply to an entire slide on a Sharepoint site. Just had to add height:100%.

Answer (score 9):

Just use "display block" for link.

```
ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block; /* or block with float left */
  /* margin HERE! */
}

li a {
  display: block;
  /* padding and border HERE! */
}
```

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/TWFwA/ :)

Comment: This won't solve the entire problem. If padding is applied to the `li` (which it is), then there will still be unclickable space around the `a` (which will take up all the horizontal space *up to* the padding.

Comment: Of course, padding should be inside link :) it's inside link in my jsfiddle sample. I think it's obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I myself just had this problem.

The answer couldn't be simpler:

```
<li class="menuitem"><a href="index.php"><div class="menulink">Lnk1</div></a></li>
Wrong:
.menuitem {
    list-style-type:        none;
    display:                 inline;
    margin-left:            5px;
    margin-right:            5px;
    font-family:            Georgia;
    font-size:                11px;
    background-color:        #c0dbf1;
    border:                 1px solid black;
    padding:                10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

Correct
.menuitem a {
    list-style-type:        none;
    display:                 block;
    margin-left:            5px;
    margin-right:            5px;
    font-family:            Georgia;
    font-size:                11px;
    background-color:        #c0dbf1;
    border:                 1px solid black;
    padding:                10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
```

in other words, you want to apply the css that the LI's had to the A element. Making sure that the A is a block line element

Comment: +1 for including code sample in your answer, and using actual CSS provided by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have meant `inline-block`, not `inner-block`:

```
li a {display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

Also, `inline-block` has its own set of problem with older IE browsers, and probably won't react how you'd expect.

Comment: Yes, I did. I might be getting too little sleep nowadays. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just format the `a` directly instead of the `li` with your styles.

I have alterd your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BrcZK/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `a` elements `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Because *appearing* clickable is not the same thing as *actually being* clickable. And it's even worse UX.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
a { display: block; }
```

Then style the anchors as I see fit.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/erik_lopez/v4P5h/

Answer (score -1):

a sir you use jquery ?
if yes, you can try it :

```
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).find('a').click();
});
```

or you could use it too as css:

```
li{
  position:relative;
}
li a {
  position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;
}
```

Choose one ...
Good luck

Comment: Not terribly good solutions this problem. jQuery is overkill (especially when there hasn't even been a mention of JavaScript). And `position: absolute` will cause the `li` to lose height and width.

Answer (score -3):

Move the `<a>` tags so that they wrap the `<li>` tags.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct) answer, anchor tags must contain inline elements, and it looks like your `<li>`'s are inline, so this should be valid.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's invalid for a `<li>` to be under anything except a `<ul>`. No `ul a li {}` allowed.

Comment: The inline or block nature of an element is defined in the HTML spec and is not changed by the CSS display property. display: inline just makes something look inline, it doesn't actually make it inline.

Comment: Actually, it's more that a `<ul>` can't contain anything except `<li>`'s.