# How to make a valid <li> link

Tags: html, css, validation

I'm trying to make an unordered list where the list items are links, not just the text inside them. But this is not valid.
When checking my code with https://validator.w3.org/check I receive the message

> Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context.

This is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style:none;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color: #212121;
            font-size: 1em;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        #container {
            padding:20px;
        }

        .valid {
            background-color:blanchedalmond;
        }

        .invalid {
            background-color:aquamarine;
        }

        .nav-item {
            width:120px;
            height:34px;
            margin:4px;
            line-height:34px;
            text-align:center;
            border: solid 1px #212121;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="valid nav-item"><a href="index.html">valid</a></li>
            <a href="index.html"><li class="invalid nav-item">invalid</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The invalid arrangement of `<a><li></li></a>` is what I want to achieve** behavior-wise with the entire `<li>` element being selectable as a link.

If I want to maintain valid code what is the best way to achieve a selectable `<li>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make whole <li> as link with proper HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745347/make-whole-li-as-link-with-proper-html)

Comment: you can add onClick event like this `<li onclick='window.location.href="http://google.com"'>Click Here</li>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation Error: Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599801/validation-error-element-a-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-ul-in-this-context)

Comment: Five people managed to post the exact same answer while failing to answer the actual question. Incredible. The OP *knows* that <li><a></a></li> is the valid way of constructing elements - this is reflected as much in the original markup. The question is not how to nest the elements validly, it is how to achieve a certain layout (not performance) using valid markup.

Comment: The question is not clear TBF.

Comment: @Liam: The last two paragraphs seem abundantly clear to me, besides the use of the word performance where layout was meant. Perhaps it's the title that needs changing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This format is **invalid**

```
<a href="index.html"><li class="invalid nav-item">invalid</li></a>
```

Valid format is

```
 <li class="invalid nav-item"><a href="index.html">valid</a></li>
```

As for your concern anchor filling up the space of `li`, little `css` trick will solve it.

```
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I've been searching through many answers, this was the only one that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 7):

There are two way you can get the li text clickable

1) Add onlclick event the the li  like 
    `<li onclick='window.location.href="Your Link"'>Your Text</li>`

2) Add a tag inside the li and add css to a tag as bellow

```
<li><a href='your link'>Your Text</a></li>

li a{
    display:block;
}
```

Second option cover inside area of li

Answer (score 6):

You cannot wrap your li in an anchor, if all you want is to make everything inside your li selectable rather than just the text, you can achieve this using CSS. Remove any defualt padding from your li tags, and make your anchors display block.

```
li {
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width:120px;
    height:34px;
}
```

this will force the anchor to fill the li and so making the entire thing clickable.

Answer (score -1):

The anchor can not contain li as its child so you have to put the anchor tag inside the li element as:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="valid nav-item"><a href="index.html">valid</a></li>
    <li class="invalid nav-item"><a href="index.html">invalid</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Just replace your ul with this.
And add the css:

```
li a{
 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 <div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="valid nav-item"><a href="index.html" title="valid">valid</a></li>
        <li class="invalid nav-item"><a href="index.html" title="invalid">invalid</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the syntax where u can't get error messages

Answer (score -4):

Replace your code with below code, you need wrap [href](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) element inside li.

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="valid nav-item"><a href="index.html">valid</a></li>
        <li class="invalid nav-item"><a href="index.html">invalid</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your up vote comment why this answer is down vote.

Answer (score -5):

Because you're missing to wrap a tag with li tag:

Replace this:

```
<ul>
   <li class="valid nav-item"><a href="index.html">valid</a></li>
   <a href="index.html"><li class="invalid nav-item">invalid</li></a>
</ul>
```

With this:

```
<ul>
   <li class="valid nav-item"><a href="index.html">valid</a></li>
   <li class="invalid nav-item"><a href="index.html">invalid</a></li>
</ul>
```