# Element ul not allowed as child of element ul (validation error)

Tags: html, css, validation

I keep getting a validation error, I tried to wrap the code in li tag but then it messes up the button tag?? is there a way to get it to work not sure where I'm going wrong is there any other tag to use instead of the button tag?

```
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="coffee-origin.html">Origins of Coffee</a></li>

  <ul class="subnav">
        <button class="subnavbtn">More About Coffee ▾ </button>

            <ul class="subnav-content">
                <li><a href="coffee-types.html"> Coffee Types</a></li>
                <li><a href="coffee-prduction.html"> Production</a></li>
                <li><a href="further-resources.html"> Further Resources</a></li>
            </ul>

  </ul>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913279/how-to-make-a-valid-li-link) help?

Comment: Why is there a button in he UL? The second UL should be in a LI, not as a child of the UL

Comment: what is validation error?

Answer (score 1):

The proper HTML should be the second UL being inside of an li and the button inside of an li.

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="coffee-origin.html">Origins of Coffee</a></li>
    <li><button class="subnavbtn">More About Coffee ▾ </button>
      <ul class="subnav-content">
        <li><a href="coffee-types.html"> Coffee Types</a></li>
        <li><a href="coffee-prduction.html"> Production</a></li>
        <li><a href="further-resources.html"> Further Resources</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a drop-down in place of that shall be better

```
<div id="dropdown">
  <button onclick="showdrop()" id="dropbtn">More About Coffee ▾</button>
  <div id="dropdown-content" style="display:none;">
      <a href="coffee-types.html"> Coffee Types</a>
      <a href="coffee-prduction.html"> Production</a>
      <a href="further-resources.html"> Further Resources</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in javascript

```
function showdrop(){
 document.getElementById('dropdown-content').style.display="block";
 
}
```